# Quick Action, Lightning Component and defa

Tags: lightning-aura-components, quickaction

I have created a Quickaction button to display a Lightning Component. When the component displays, I have 4 fields from current record; ID, Latitude, Longitude, and Date-Time field. The lat, lng, date fields are blank but I would like to pre-populate them with data along with the current ID.

I can display the ID of current record and I'm able to retrieve the geolocation values from the browser, but I can't get the new values for the remaining fields to display along with the ID when the component opens. I'm stuck on combing the current record ID and new data together to display in component.

Appreciate any help/direction.

R[image]

Comment: It would be easier if you share the component code. Are you using `force:recordData` to retrieve record info?